# Что такое  String.valueOf()?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет! Хотел понять, что такое `String.valueOf()`.

Это означает, что преобразует все в строку (число, булеан и т.д.)?

Answer (score 3):

Есть очень полезный документ: [документация Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). 
Там этот метод описан.

Comment: А на русском есть?

Comment: Нет. Учите английский. Без английского в программировании делать нечего.

Comment: @duddeniska, стоит начать учить английский.

Comment: А всего лишь попросил ответить на вопрос! Что за народ! Два предложения ленятся написать!

Comment: В некоторых пределах русскоязычной альтернативой может служить [Кей Хорстманн](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3817476/)

![][http://i.imgur.com/2zayHvv.jpg]

Comment: > а всего лишь попросил ответить на вопрос

Вопросы по основам основ, которые бы не возникли после прочтения любого учебника по java, тут не сильно приветствуются.

Comment: Можно изучить язык 1С - он полностью на русском! :)

Comment: @argamidon, упаси Господи :D

Answer (score 1):

Преобразует в строку число или другой параметр.